# Python3 print statement prints 0 instead of the actual return value of the function

Tags: python, printing

I am doing AOC 2020 and I am seeing something weird with python3 print statement and I don't understand what's going on.

This question is day 6 part 1 and it is suppose to count a bunch of chars in a file and basically find out how many is counted.

This is my code below, and when I run it on my Pycharm 2020.3 in Win 10 with Python 3.5, these two print statements gives wildly different results:

The `print(a)` line gives me what I expect, the value returned from process_customs_data.
The `print(process_customs_data(customs_data))` gives me 0 which makes no sense shouldn't it print the return value of the function?

and just as an extra test I changed `total_count =total_count + a` with `total_count =total_count + process_customs_data(customs_data)` and both scenarios works. I can see my total count updated correctly.

[image]

```
import pprint
from aocd.models import Puzzle
from aocd import submit
import time

def process_customs_data(data):
    pprint.pprint(set(data))

    return len(set(data))

puzzle = Puzzle(year=2020, day=6)

raw = puzzle.input_data
data = raw.splitlines()

total_count = 0
customs_data = ""

for line in data:

    if line == '':
        a = process_customs_data(customs_data)
        total_count =total_count + a
        customs_data = ''
        print(a)
        print(process_customs_data(customs_data))
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        customs_data = customs_data + line.strip()

print(total_count)


#submit(total_count, part="a", day=6, year=2020)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `print(process_customs_data(customs_data))` command prints the actual return value of the expression `process_customs_data(customs_data)`.

And if you are wondering, why that's different from `a`, then just see that you updated function argument `customs_data = ''` before calling your function.

In your function `process_customs_data(data)` you create a `set` that will contain all possible different characters from your string. For the call with the empty `data` it will be the empty set, so the `len` of the empty set is 0. And `print` prints this 0.